# Compositing effects not showing in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I added compositing/post processing effects in my project. I tried to add a bloom effect with cycles render engine using composting/post processing, I did it in cycles because what I want is not working with eevee, so I cannot use eevee's bloom. So when I render my project the composting/post processing effects is not showing in the rendered result, neither with the render image button or render animation button. Anyone who can fix my problem, write it in the comments or answers.
I always get my question answered by @moonboots, Thanks to @moonboots for answering my previous question.

This is my .blender file link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsB_Y-fJ9d30CS3TjZ0BgFoU3uyvwANc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Connect the Glare Image output to the Composite node Image input and try again.

Comment: Worked! Thank you.